# Inserting entity object data in database using Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf

I am thoroughly new to the Oracle ADF technology. I have dropped an entity view object from the Data Control Palette to a jspx page, and created an adf creation form from it. I am not understanding how the information input in the form will reflect in the database. Pls help.

PS: The new row is getting added in the adf read-only table which I have added on the same page

Comment: With Form it is similar to Table . So drop `create insert ` operation from view object under your data control . Also Drag and drop commit button to the page . Now Run your .jspx page , click on createinsert button , enter the values and click on commit page , the data will be saved to the database

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you learn how the technology works. This is a LARGE ORM/UI framework and needs to be learned.
There is a lot of free training [here](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=44785:24:0::NO::P24_CONTENT_ID,P24_PREV_PAGE:6022,1), [here](http://download.oracle.com/tutorials/jtcd3/ecourse_adf_part2/html/temp_frameset/index.htm) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/adf/learnmore/adfinsider-093342.html).
 I also recommend this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071602380).
There's even a Getting Started with ADF (via google) Page [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/overview/jdeveloper-reviewrguide-086026.html).

Answer (score 0):

User
When you drop a viewObject based on entityObject on page then you are able to perform DML operation on that 
To create new row drop createInsert operation from DataControl and make readOnly false for table inorder to inputValue or use a form
then drop commit operation from DataControl on page .
After entering records press commit button to save it in DB
Data is validated through binding layer and committed to DB from model itlsef
Check these blog for more information-
http://se7so.blogspot.in/2014/02/sample-adf-crud-web-application.html
http://andrejusb.blogspot.in/2009/11/crud-operations-in-jdeveloperadf-11g-r1.html

Ashish